# How to use image4j Library?

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to create a program that can display *.ico file, so when I tried to search on google it's display for this library. I'm running with bluej and try to run the sample test.java and it's shown an error "package net.sf.image4j.codec.ico does not exist"

I'm running this with bluej, so I tried to add image4j-example.jar to bluej library but nothing happen. What am I supposed to do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check the list of packages that are included in the image4j-example.jar file.  It sounds from the name like that JAR file contains examples of how to use the library but not the image4j library itself.  You can go here to download the image4j library:

http://image4j.sourceforge.net/

Once you download the .zip file from there and unpack it you should see a folder titled 'image4j-core-0.7'.  Inside that folder is an image4j.jar file.  I checked it in my IDE and that JAR file does have the net.sf.image4j.codec.ico package.  Add that library to your project and give it another shot.

Comment: it's worked. But how to display an ico files to my java program? so I want to select ico file using JFileChooser and then display the selected ico file on my program. Thanks